# unable to retrieve field values from object laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to use eloquent relationships to retrieve some data from my DB. I am running into an issue when trying to get specific fields rather than the full object. Here is some of my code.

Controller:

```
    public function getHosts($table = null)
    {

            foreach (Hosts::all() as $host)
            {
               echo $host->physical_machine_name;
               echo $host->app->id;
            }
     }
```

models:

```
class Hosts extends Eloquent
{
    protected $connection = 'mysql_2';
    protected $table = 'hosts';
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function app(){
            return $this->hasMany('Apps', 'os_instance_name')->orWhere('os_instance_name', $this->os_instance_name);
    }

}

class Apps extends Eloquent
{
    protected $connection = 'mysql_2';
    protected $table = 'app_instances';
    public $timestamps = false;

     public function host()
     {
           return $this->belongsTo('Hosts','os_instance_name')->orWhere('os_instance_name', $this->os_instance_name);
     }

}
```

I am not able to get the id of the app to display but when I remove the '->id' specifier i am able to get a json object containing all of the fields. Why is this happening?

I should also note that the `$host->physical_machine_name` works fine.

this is the error I receive:

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$id
```

I am also unable to use eager loading because I am using custom foreign keys in my relationships.

Comment: If `$host->app` is an `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection` then you wrote an incorrect mapping, most likely a `hasMany` insteand of a `belongsTo`. Can you post the definitions of `Hosts` and `App`, or whatever's the name of each item in the `$hosts->app` collection?

Comment: I have added the models to the question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are defining `apps` as a `hasMany` relationship. This means `apps` will be a collection of entities, not a single one, hence the `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection` instance, as Laravel uses this class for lists of entities populated by Eloquent.
Being a collection of entities you won't have any properties of the `App` entity on it.

Instead of `echo $host->app->id;` you can

```
foreach($host->app as $app) {
    echo $app->id;
}
```

Comment: this works, but according to the laravel documentation it should work how I was using it before...http://four.laravel.com/docs/eloquent#querying-relations

Comment: That example is for a `belongsTo` relation. I recommend reading Doctrine's docs here http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html They explain one-to-many relationships better than the Laravel Eloquent docs can.